# Loading third party add-in then activating ribbon tab on open

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon, excel-addins

I'm using office 2007 and trying to activate the ribbon tab after loading on open. It's not working for me. I've tried all the solutions that said works didn't work. Anyone have any idea? Here's my code

Here's my ribbon from UI Editor:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon startFromScratch="false" >
<tabs>
    <tab id="tabColtar" label="Controls" keytip="B">
    ....
    .....
```

Here's my workbook open event in excel

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Workbooks.Open ("C:\myAddin.xlam"), , True
    Workbooks("myAddin.xlam.xlam").IsAddin = True
    Application.SendKeys "%B%"
```

Seems like it's not loading my addin therefore it gets stuck at the pressing Atl key.

Comment: are you trying to install the add-in once it is opened?

Comment: no, i'm trying to activate that addin tab when it is open on a workbook.

Comment: You don't need to do that. If you save it as an `xlsm` file it will carry the add-in and when that workbook is open and active, it will show the ribbon

Comment: thats right, when i open my .xlsm file it is suppose to load the add in to that workbook. thing is, it is not activating it.

Comment: then there is a problem with your `xml`, can you upload your workbook so that I can have a look?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: The way you develop an add-in is to add a ribbon to the xlsm file in xml language and then save it as xlam, if you cannot see that in the xlsm version, then your xml code is not doing its job